# Does Jonathan Culler view literary theory itself as a historical construction?

Tags: theory, literary-theory-short-introduction, jonathan-culler

*Literary Theory: a Very Short Introduction* by Jonathan Culler has the following quote in it (in chapter 1 of the 2nd edition):

> Theory is often a pugnacious critique of common-sense notations, and further, an attempt to show that what we take fro granted as "common sense" is in fact an historical construction, a particular theory that has come to seem so natural to us that we don't even see it as a theory.

This isn't actually stated in the book (at least not that I've read so far), but does Culler view theory itself as a historical construction?